# How to fix the error 'module' object has no attribute 'UnexpectedResponse' in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

Here is the playbook for your reference:

```
---
- name: Closing notes
  hosts: XXXX
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Modify a change request
    snow_record:
      state: present
      table: change_request
      username: admin
      password: XXXXX
      instance: XXXXX
      number: XXXXX
      data:
        state: -3
    register: incident

  - debug:
      var: incident.record.state
```

Output:

> fatal: [XXXXXXX]: FAILED! => {
>       "changed": false,
>       "module_stderr": "Shared connection to XXXXXXX closed.\r\n",
>       "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1577091421.74-160409156883610/AnsiballZ_snow_record.py\", line 114, in \r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1577091421.74-160409156883610/AnsiballZ_snow_record.py\", line 106, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1577091421.74-160409156883610/AnsiballZ_snow_record.py\", line 49, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('**main**', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_snow_record_payload_qHs01F/**main**.py\", line 334, in \r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_snow_record_payload_qHs01F/**main**.py\", line 330, in main\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_snow_record_payload_qHs01F/**main**.py\", line 319, in run_module\r\nAttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UnexpectedResponse'\r\n",
>       "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
>       "rc": 1
>   }

Comment: ---
- name: Closing ticket in service now
  hosts: XXXXX
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Modify a change request
    snow_record:
      state: present
      table: change_request
      username: admin
      password: XXXXXX
      instance: XXXXXX
      number: CHG0030002
      data:
        state: -3
    register: incident

  - debug:
      var: incident.record.state
~

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/41148 This seems to be an issue/bug in ansible snow_record module

Answer (score 0):

需要指定python的环境为 python3，就可以解决
You need to make the Python environment as Python 3, you can solve this problem

eg

[all:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3

Comment: Qustion, is the non-english (Chinese maybe?) part of the answer relevant? If yes, can you translate them to English? If not, can you remove them, as they only add noise otherwise? Thanks,